# jQuery closest not traversing past parent

Tags: jquery

I'm after an input that's inside 3 `divs`, a `td`, and a `tr`.  There are no usable unique attributes to search with (id's and rows change frequently). I'm trying to traverse the DOM by starting with a `label` in a `div` in an adjacent `td`, go to the `next td`, then down through a `div` a `div` another `div` then into the `input`.

I started with `$('[title*="P2P"]').closest('td').next('.control-cell').find('input');`

It doesn't select the input for me, so I started working backwards by printing the class of the selected element 1 step at a time, but it breaks as soon as use `closest` to go past the first `div`.

My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/28kacj28/

And my HTML:

```
<tr class="control">
  <td class="label-cell left-label">
    <div class="workitemlabel">
      <label class="workitemcontrol-label" for="witc_135_txt" title="[Field Name: Process Start Date]">Start Date:</label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="control-cell">
    <div class="workitemcontrol">
      <div id="witc_135" class="combo input-text-box date-time drop">
        <div class="wrap">
          <input type="text" id="witc_135_txt" autocomplete="off" maxlength="255" title="7/7/2016 12:00:00 AM" aria-invalid="false">
        </div>
        <div class="drop bowtie-calendar bowtie-icon"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="control">
  <td class="label-cell left-label">
    <div class="workitemlabel">
      <label class="workitemcontrol-label" for="witc_136_txt" title="[Field Name: P2P]">P2P:</label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="control-cell">
    <div class="workitemcontrol">
      <div id="witc_136" class="combo input-text-box date-time drop">
        <div class="wrap">
          <input type="text" id="witc_136_txt" autocomplete="off" maxlength="255" title="7/29/2016 12:00:00 AM" aria-invalid="false">
        </div>
        <div class="drop bowtie-calendar bowtie-icon"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<span></span>
```

Comment: [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) doesn't do what you think it does. It will traverse up to the ancestors of the tree like `parents()`.

Comment: `testShit is not defined` in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to select but you made two mistakes:

1. Wrap table elements ( `<tr>`, `<td>` ) with a table. Browsers will remove `tr` and `td` tags automatically and dynamically (meaning "View Source..." will still show the tags even though they were removed) when they are not properly wrapped by a `table` tag. This means the `tr.control` tag was not being found.
2. Your class variable `testClass` was being assigned from the undefined (misspelled) variable `testShit` instead of `testStuff` (line 2). Keep it classy.

I made corrections in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/28kacj28/3/

Comment: If you use the F12 tools you will see what the browser is rendering and the tr and td tags have been removed from the DOM tree

Comment: Thanks, it was just the table tags.  I'm brain dead today.